# Using weak pointers that evaluate to a None type

Tags: c++, boost-python

In my implementation for python integration into a c++ application, I am adding support for nodes that might or might not be valid. Internally these are stored as weak pointers, so I was thinking of having an isValid() method that users can use before calling the exposed methods. If they call an exposed method on an invalid node it would throw an exception.

However, I was wondering if it's possible to be a bit more pythonic than that. Is it possible to internally check whether the pointer is valid before calling the exposed method, and if it isn't making the python object None?

An example of what I want is here:

```
>>> my_valid_node = corelibrary.getNode("valid_node")
>>> my_valid_node.printName()
valid_node
```

Now however, something somewhere else in the system might invalidate the node, but from python's point of view, I want the node to become None.

```
>>> my_valid_node.printName()
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'printName'
```

Can anyone think of a way to do this?

Comment: Use a class which stores the pointer and a second attribute `isvalid`.

Comment: How would that set the node to None?

Comment: `if not isvalid: set node to None` but why even setting to `None`? `if not isvalid: raise AttributeError`.

Comment: My point is that I don't want the python user to have to think about it. What I can do is have something like: `if node.isValid(): do stuff` but what I want to be able to do is `if node: do stuff`

Comment: Implement the method `__nonzero__(self): return isvalid`, see https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__nonzero__ .

Comment: That gets me part of the way there, but it still gives the users access to the methods of the object. So say I have an object called `node` if the users do actually do `if node: node.printName()` then that will work, but if they actually do `node.printName()` without checking, it'll attempt to run that function. I supposed I could raise the exception internally in that case.

Comment: Yes you can check within the method `printName()` whether this node is valid or not and raise an exception accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no *clean* way to make a reference to an object become a reference to `None` when an external event occurs.  Nevertheless, when working towards a Pythonic interface, one could:

- Implement the [`__nonzero__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__nonzero__) method to allow the object to be evaluated in a boolean context.
- Throw a Python exception when the `weak_ptr` fails to lock.  One simple solution, would be to access a member attribute on a default constructed `boost::python::object`, as it references `None`.

Note that attribute lookup customization points, such as [`__getattr__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__), will not be sufficient enough as the object pointed to by `weak_ptr` may expire between attribute access and dispatch to the C++ member functions.

---

Here is a complete minimal example based on the above details.  In this example, `spam` and `spam_factory`, a factory that instantiates `spam` objects managed by `shared_ptr`, are considered legacy types.  A `spam_proxy` auxiliary class that references `spam` via `weak_ptr` and additionally auxiliary functions help adapt the legacy types to Python.

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/smart_ptr/weak_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/python.hpp>

/// Assume legacy APIs.

// Mockup class containing data.
class spam
{
public:
  explicit spam(const char* name)
   : name_(name)
  {}

  std::string name() { return name_; }

private:
  std::string name_;
};

// Factory for creating and destroying the mockup class.
class spam_factory
{
public:
  boost::shared_ptr<spam> create(const char* name)
  {
    instance_ = boost::make_shared<spam>(name);
    return instance_;
  }

  void destroy()
  {
    instance_.reset();
  }

private:
  boost::shared_ptr<spam> instance_;
};

/// Auxiliary classes and functions to help obtain Pythonic semantics.

// Helper function used to cause a Python AttributeError exception to
// be thrown on None.
void throw_none_has_no_attribute(const char* attr)
{
  // Attempt to extract the specified attribute on a None object.
  namespace python = boost::python;
  python::object none;
  python::extract<python::object>(none.attr(attr))();
}

// Mockup proxy that has weak-ownership.
class spam_proxy
{
public:
  explicit spam_proxy(const boost::shared_ptr<spam>& impl)
    : impl_(impl)
  {}

  std::string name() const  { return lock("name")->name(); }
  bool is_valid() const     { return !impl_.expired();     }

  boost::shared_ptr<spam> lock(const char* attr) const
  {
    // Attempt to obtain a shared pointer from the weak pointer.
    boost::shared_ptr<spam> impl = impl_.lock();

    // If the objects lifetime has ended, then throw.
    if (!impl) throw_none_has_no_attribute(attr);

    return impl;
  }

private:
  boost::weak_ptr<spam> impl_;
};

// Use a factory to create a spam instance, but wrap it in the proxy.
spam_proxy spam_factory_create(
  spam_factory& self,
  const char* name)
{
  return spam_proxy(self.create(name));
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
  namespace python = boost::python;

  // Expose the proxy class as if it was the actual class.
  python::class_<spam_proxy>("Spam", python::no_init)
    .def("__nonzero__", &spam_proxy::is_valid)
    .add_property("name", &spam_proxy::name)
    ;

  python::class_<spam_factory>("SpamFactory")
    .def("create", &spam_factory_create) // expose auxiliary method
    .def("destroy", &spam_factory::destroy)
    ;
}
```

Interactive usage:

```python
>>> import example
>>> factory = example.SpamFactory()
>>> spam = factory.create("test")
>>> assert(spam.name == "test")
>>> assert(bool(spam) == True)
>>> if spam:
...     assert(bool(spam) == True)
...     factory.destroy() # Maybe occurring from a C++ thread.
...     assert(bool(spam) == False) # Confusing semantics.
...     assert(spam.name == "test") # Confusing exception.
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'
>>> assert(spam is not None) # Confusing type.
```

One could argue that while the interface is Pythonic, the object's semantics are not.  With `weak_ptr` semantics not being too common in Python, one generally does not expect the object referenced by a local variable to be destructed.  If `weak_ptr` semantics are necessary, then consider introducing a means to allow the user to obtain shared ownership within a specific context via the [context manager protocol](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#context-manager-types).  For example, the following pattern allows an object's validity to be checked once, then be guaranteed within a limited scope:

```python
>>> with spam:                # Attempt to acquire shared ownership.
...     if spam:              # Verify ownership was obtained.
...         spam.name         # Valid within the context's scope.
...         factory.destroy() # spam is still valid.
...         spam.name         # Still valid.
...                           # spam destroyed once context's scope is exited.
```

Here is a complete extension of the previous example, where in the `spam_proxy` implements the context manager protocol:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/smart_ptr/weak_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/python.hpp>

/// Assume legacy APIs.

// Mockup class containing data.
class spam
{
public:
  explicit spam(const char* name)
   : name_(name)
  {}

  std::string name() { return name_; }

private:
  std::string name_;
};

// Factory for creating and destroying the mockup class.
class spam_factory
{
public:
  boost::shared_ptr<spam> create(const char* name)
  {
    instance_ = boost::make_shared<spam>(name);
    return instance_;
  }

  void destroy()
  {
    instance_.reset();
  }

private:
  boost::shared_ptr<spam> instance_;
};

/// Auxiliary classes and functions to help obtain Pythonic semantics.

// Helper function used to cause a Python AttributeError exception to
// be thrown on None.
void throw_none_has_no_attribute(const char* attr)
{
  // Attempt to extract the specified attribute on a None object.
  namespace python = boost::python;
  python::object none;
  python::extract<python::object>(none.attr(attr))();
}

// Mockup proxy that has weak-ownership and optional shared ownership.
class spam_proxy
{
public:
  explicit spam_proxy(const boost::shared_ptr<spam>& impl)
    : shared_impl_(),
      impl_(impl)
  {}

  std::string name() const  { return lock("name")->name(); }
  bool is_valid() const     { return !impl_.expired();     }

  boost::shared_ptr<spam> lock(const char* attr) const
  {
    // If shared ownership exists, return it.
    if (shared_impl_) return shared_impl_;

    // Attempt to obtain a shared pointer from the weak pointer.
    boost::shared_ptr<spam> impl = impl_.lock();

    // If the objects lifetime has ended, then throw.
    if (!impl) throw_none_has_no_attribute(attr);

    return impl;
  }

  void enter()
  {
    // Upon entering the runtime context, guarantee the lifetime of the
    // object remains until the runtime context exits if the object is
    // alive during this call.
    shared_impl_ = impl_.lock();
  }

  bool exit(boost::python::object type,
            boost::python::object value,
            boost::python::object traceback)
  {
    shared_impl_.reset();
    return false; // Do not suppress the exception.
  }

private:
  boost::shared_ptr<spam> shared_impl_;
  boost::weak_ptr<spam> impl_;
};

// Use a factory to create a spam instance, but wrap it in the proxy.
spam_proxy spam_factory_create(
  spam_factory& self,
  const char* name)
{
  return spam_proxy(self.create(name));
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
  namespace python = boost::python;

  // Expose the proxy class as if it was the actual class.
  python::class_<spam_proxy>("Spam", python::no_init)
    .def("__nonzero__", &spam_proxy::is_valid)
    // Support context manager protocol.
    .def("__enter__", &spam_proxy::enter)
    .def("__exit__", &spam_proxy::exit)
    .add_property("name", &spam_proxy::name)
    ;

  python::class_<spam_factory>("SpamFactory")
    .def("create", &spam_factory_create) // expose auxiliary method
    .def("destroy", &spam_factory::destroy)
    ;
}
```

Interactive usage:

```python
>>> import example
>>> factory = example.SpamFactory()
>>> spam = factory.create("test")
>>> with spam:
...     assert(bool(spam) == True)
...     if spam:
...         assert(spam.name == "test")
...         factory.destroy()
...         assert(bool(spam) == True)
...         assert(spam.name == "test")
... 
>>> assert(bool(spam) == False)
```

The exact pattern may not be the most Pythonic, but it provides a clean way to guarantee the object's lifetime within a limited scope.

Comment: Really useful answer, thank you. I think the first example is more appropriate for me as there are a lot of automatic cleanup mechanisms for resources within the application. The python integration is implemented as a console, so resources that should be cleaned up could be left hanging around if the python object had shared ownership. Your attribute throwing mechanism works really well :).